# How to play Bluray?

Tags: 12.04, mount, dell, blu-ray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I watch Blu-ray discs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9912/how-can-i-watch-blu-ray-discs)

How can i play Bluray discs on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit?

When i put the disc in my laptop it doesn't even get mounted.

```
jeggy@localhost:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009f0f2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   195518463    97655808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       195520510   976771071   390625281    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       195520512   218957823    11718656   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       218959872   976771071   378905600   83  Linux
```

I have a Dell XPS 15 which should be able to play bluray discs.

This is what it says on [Official Dell site](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-l502x/pd)

```
8x DVD+/-RW (standard), Blu-ray Disc™ combo (reads Blu-ray Disc™ & writes to CD/DVD); 12.7mm tray load
```